# C Find Computer on LAN With Open Server

Tags: c, sockets

Im trying to figure out a way for one user to open a server, on a port of their choice, and for a user on the same LAN, to be able to see that server without manually putting in the ip and port. Think like when you open a minecraft LAN server, and people on the LAN can see the server, even though they never put in the ip, and the port is different every time. Is there a way to do this in c on linux with the Berkley Sockets API, with TCP sockets?

Comment: my 2 cents... you don't know what you don't know. I don't know how Minecraft works, but it isn't magic. It's probably using some discovery protocol where it's sending out beacons that the clients are listening for. You can do some googling or network sniffing to figure it out. I'm sure there are several protocols like this that already exist, and I wouldn't recommend trying to spin your own unless it's for your own enlightenment. The most straightforward way to discover open ports is to port scan... unless you're talking UDP ports in which case port scanning isn't reliable.

Comment: Apple call one protocol that provides discovery “Bonjour” - not tied to Apple, you will find information by goggling.

Comment: On a LAN, the classic technique is to use a UDP broadcast to advertise an available service.

Comment: Yes but no point reinventing the wheel, as @yano also points out, and who knows what other discovery services a homegrown hackaprotocol might conflict with/break, is there?

Comment: It's not like UDP broadcasts are particularly complex, especially if you're already writing a TCP server in C. Here's a simple example that looks a lot like what the OP is trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071415/sending-broadcast-server-client-and-sending-back-client-server-udp-c-socke

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of articles out there on how to use Unix built-in's to scan your Local Area Network for other hosts.

You can find your own IP address and Network using ifconfig, like in [this article](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-find-what-devices-are-connected-to-network-in-ubuntu/).

It's then a simple task to get a list of IP's/hostnames on your LAN using a command like [`nmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nmap.1.html), and then sort through the output.

Here's an example:

```
sudo nmap -sn 10.84.32.54/24 | grep -Po "(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}"
```

Which will return you a list of ip-addresses on your network like:

```
10.84.32.1
10.84.32.11
10.84.32.12
10.84.32.14
10.84.32.17
```

You could then go about scan each of the ports on these by running:

```
nmap -p- 10.84.32.1
```

To get an output like:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
2581/tcp open  unknown
2443/tcp open  unknown
```